# How to Call webservice and get json response using phonegap for iphone

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.5

I'm very new to phonegap. I installed the `phonegap2.1.0` in `xcode4.5`. Now phonegap is working fine. But how can I call a webservice and get a json response for phonegap? My code is below, but it isn't working. Can anybody help me?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
    alert("alert");
    url: "http://localhost:55022/WebSite1/sample.asmx/returnEmployees",
    data: null,
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg, textStatus, jqXHR){
            alert(textStatus);
            //var theRealData = msg.d;
           /*
           $.each(theRealData.employees, function (index, item) {
           // at this point, item is an array, since theRealData.employees is an array of arrays
           var col1 = item[0];
           var col2 = item[1];
           alert(col1);
           }); */
    },error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.log(textStatus +"------" +errorThrown + jqXHR );
    // navigator.notification.alert('Server Error');
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: not write success: success: just success:

Comment: try success: function(msg, textStatus, jqXHR)... like Mehmet suggest.
If you still have problems take a look to your console, do you get any errors?

Comment: @F481 Thanks for reply. Am not getting any error in my console. You have any idea.

Comment: @Mehmet This time also am not getting the result.

Comment: @Mehmet Thanks for reply.I have edited my question. Please go through my question. Then let me know the answer.

Comment: you are using asp.net local server with debug your service. Is it running now? I am using IIS for my projects.

Comment: and add contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" to jquery ajax method..

Comment: and look at http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/ this blog. It has great samples with asp.net web service and jquery ajax.

Comment: @Mehmet Thanks for your reply. I have edited my question. Please go through my question and let me know your commands. I have put the alert inside the  $.ajax function. But that alert was not working. So that  $.ajax function is not working. How can i call that. PLease help me to solve this issue

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18630/discussion-between-mehmet-and-gopinath-m)

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using "localhost" when you run this code on a device/emulator then "localhost" refers to the device/emulator itself and not the web server that contains your rails API. You'll need to switch "localhost" to the IP address or hostname of your server.